# Grouping DataFrame rows given a row-dependent condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem i cannot solve.
I have a DataFrame in which every row is a "person" with one or two connections with another row. Every person has got an ID, and the connection is expressed in the columns COMPANION1 and COMPANION2, where will appear the ID of the person connected.
I have to bind with Pandas every "group", maybe by creating a new column with a number associated with the group.
It's easier to look ad the DF:

```
array = np.array([['A', 'B', 0], ['B', 'A', 0], ['C','D', 0], 
                  ['D', 'C', 0], ['E', 'G','F'], ['F','E','G'], 
                  ['G', 0, 0]])
index_values = ['0', '1', '2',
                '3', '4', '5', '6']
column_values = ['ID', 'COMPANION1', 'COMPANION2']
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data = array, 
                  index = index_values, 
                  columns = column_values)
  
df['GROUP'] = np.zeros(len(df))
df
```

[Dataframe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd47E.png)

The original dataset is way bigger than this (circa 1600 rows).
In this example, A-B are bound, as C-D, and then E-F-G (yes, not every "person" has links, but it is sufficient to check if others have links to the ones without any).
How can i assign a "index" to every family? I'm sure there are no unbound people as well every family is a "closed system", and no family is bigger than 3.

I hope i've been clear enough!
Thanks a lot,
Samuel

Comment: Could you share your desired result?

Comment: It could be the GROUP column made by [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: Does a 'group' constitute a combination of the same individuals, whether it's [A, B] or [B, A], such that rows 0 and 1 in your DF would be in the same group?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I need! So i can sort by group later!

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Ok, I think this solves the issue of G being in its own group:

```py
# Step 1, create groups
>>> groups = [sorted([j for j in i if j != '0']) for i in list(df['ID'] + df['COMPANION1'] + df['COMPANION2'])]
# Get groups that are actually groups, not just one-offs
>>> groups = [g for g in groups if len(g) > 1]

{['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['C',' D'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'G']}

# Convert groups to strings and get only the unique ones
>>> groups = set(["".join(g) for g in groups])

{"AB", "CD", "EFG"}

# Step 2, fill in groups
>>> df['Group'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in groups if x in i][0])

  ID COMPANION1 COMPANION2 Group
0  A          B          0    AB
1  B          A          0    AB
2  C          D          0    CD
3  D          C          0    CD
4  E          G          F   EFG
5  F          E          G   EFG
6  G          0          0   EFG
```

Then you could continue as below to assign numbers to the groups

---

### Original

The simplest way I'm seeing to do this is to create a new column with the group members:

```py
df['Members'] = df['ID'] + df['COMPANION1'] + df['COMPANION2']
df['Members'] = df['Members'].apply(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x)))

ID COMPANION1 COMPANION2 Members
0  A          B          0     0AB
1  B          A          0     0AB
2  C          D          0     0CD
3  D          C          0     0CD
4  E          G          F     EFG
5  F          E          G     EFG
6  G          0          0     00G
```

If you wanted to have numeric group IDs instead, you could do:

```py
df["Group_Id"] = df["Members"].copy().replace({gid: i for i, gid in enumerate(df["Members"].unique())})

ID COMPANION1 COMPANION2 Members  Group_Id
0  A          B          0     0AB         0
1  B          A          0     0AB         0
2  C          D          0     0CD         1
3  D          C          0     0CD         1
4  E          G          F     EFG         2
5  F          E          G     EFG         2
6  G          0          0     00G         3
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! The second one is surely better, since the IDs will be long numbers, and adding them together is not ideal. There is only the problem G is in a different family from E and F: is it possible to include the "G people"?

Comment: I think that's possible with a slightly different approach. Let me look.

Comment: @AiyaEarendil ok, updated it, lmk if that helps!

Comment: Hi! I have a problem with the original dataset. The line "df['Group'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in groups if x in i][0])" gives me this error: "list index out of range". The IDs and companion IDs are each made by long numbers (19 digits), which i converted in string before applying the solution: maybe the strings are too long? Should i post a screen of the real df?

Comment: @AiyaEarendil ah ok, I believe the issue is that when the code filters `len(g) > 1`, that will always be true since the IDs are 19 characters long. I've updated my edited solution to fix this (I believe).

Comment: I'm sorry, unluckily it still does not work, same error... Maybe i missed giving any detail? Right now I'm trying to work around it by exporting the rows as numpy array rows and working on them, maybe way slower but i don't know how to fix it! Working directy on Pandas values while iterating seems to be impossible because i can't get indexes

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the specific error, but in the lambda you could add an else: `lambda x: [i if x in i else "0" for i in groups ][0]`. This should always give you a default value and avoid index errors. As far as what's causing this specific issue in your case, it's hard to say.